# PyQt5 add widgets with a loop dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

I'm trying to write a simple program that will display pc drives information like letter assigned, total memory in GB etc. 
Since everyone has a different number of drives this must be dynamic. I am using PyQt5 for GUI.
I am trying to display letters of my drives but I can't seem to be able to dynamically add new widgets, I always get the last letter only.
Here's how it looks like now.
First I setup a grid:

```
self.gridLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.gridLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 741, 71))
self.gridLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_3")
self.DrivesData = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
self.DrivesData.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.DrivesData.setObjectName("DrivesData")
```

Then I try to add new label widgets depending on the number of drives:

```
for disk in disksInfo:
    self.DRIVELETTERSPACE = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
    self.DRIVELETTERSPACE.setObjectName("DRIVELETTERSPACE")
    self.DrivesData.addWidget(self.DRIVELETTERSPACE, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

With the above code all I get displayed is the last drive's letter(E:). 
I think I understand that I shouldn't name all of them DRIVELETTERSPACE but then how can I make the names dynamic as well?
Also, is this how I can dynamically add widgets in pyqt5? Or should I make the grid dynamic as well?
Thanks.

Comment: try with `key = 0 for disk in disksInfo:
    DRIVELETTERSPACE = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_3)
    DRIVELETTERSPACE.setObjectName("DRIVELETTERSPACE")
    DrivesData.addWidget(self.DRIVELETTERSPACE, key, 0) key += 1`

Comment: You have to add the widget to a different row and column, besides do not use self for a variable that is being updated in a loop since it could be eliminating the previous data.

Comment: This seems to be working. I think I need to assign a dynamic name as well. Any idea how could this be done(I'm going to try now).

Comment: you could create a list or a dictionary that is a member of the class where you store the variables.

Comment: Allow me to elaborate a bit. The previous loop created a new widget for each drive in the loop. I can see in gui that there's extra space created. I also have another loop for displaying the disk letters in those widgets. Here's how it looks like: `for disk in disksInfo:
            diskLetter = disk.Caption
            DRIVELETTERSPACE.setText(_translate("MainWindow", diskLetter))`

Comment: Alright, got it now. How can I check your post as an answer?

Comment: I already publish my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have 2 errors, the first case is that you are adding the widget to the same position for it you must create some method to be able to vary the indices; the other error is to create a member of the class as iterator, for this you just delete self, for example:

```
key = 0 
for disk in disksInfo: 
    DRIVELETTERSPACE = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget_3) 
    DRIVELETTERSPACE.setObjectName("DRIVELETTERSPACE") 
    DrivesData.addWidget(DRIVELETTERSPACE, key, 0) 
    key += 1
```

If you want to save the widget it is advisable to save them in a list or dictionary since later we can obtain them through an index or key, respectively.